# Fatal error after updating template, skin, layout and default in 1.8 CE

Tags: magento-1.8, php, fatal-error, default

I'm in serious need of help ASAP. I have numerous stores set up inside a Magento install, and they're all (including the Magento admin) resulting in the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function addHandle() on a non-object in /home/USERNAME/public_html/store/includes/src/__default.php on line 13860

Here are lines 13857-13861 in that file:

```
 {
        // if handles were specified in arguments load them first
        if (false!==$handles && ''!==$handles) {
            $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles ? $handles : 'default');
        }
```

Here's what broke it all. I had just uploaded theme files In the Magento admin, I went to System > Configuration, then to the General > Design tab, and opened the Themes section . I set the configuration scope to a website level, and then put the name of the theme in the Template, Skin, Layout and Default fields. When I clicked 'Save Cofig', it resulted in the error. I'm running Magento 1.8 CE.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that's in includes/src, is compiled code. Disabling your compiler will most likely get your shop running again. go into the src/config.php and comment out these lines like this:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Commenting out these lines will disable the compiler. Be sure to also refresh your cache, or at least clear it by deleting everything that's in var/cache.

Afterwards, you can recompile everything from the backend. Never upload new code when your compiler is active. In my opinion, don't use the compiler. It gives frequent trouble.

The reason your getting this error is because the theme you uploaded is not within the compiled code, while Magento is looking for it. non-object.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is good to know. Unfortunately, we were forced to restore from a backup about a week old. It could have been worse. But again thanks. I'll save the info for future reference.